# Side Label with forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I would like to add a label on the right of each node using forest.

```
\tikzset{
  rect/.append  style={rectangle, align=center,rounded corners=2pt, label={[fill=yellow,font=\tiny]0:#1}, font=\tiny, draw=black},
}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        s sep=0.1cm,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries,
        line width=0.5pt,
        rect,
        child anchor=north,
        parent anchor=south,
        l sep+=12.5pt,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[rounded corners=5pt, line width=0.5pt, ->, \forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -|
            (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
    }
    [ Parent,  label=My label
        [Variant 1 ]
        [Variant 2 ]
    ]
\end{forest}
```

[image]

I would like to put «My Label» into the yellow box

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `rect` style and pass the text as an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  rect/.append  style={rectangle, align=center,rounded corners=2pt, label={[fill=yellow,font=\tiny]0:#1}, font=\tiny, draw=black},
}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        s sep=2cm,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries,
        line width=0.5pt,
        %rect,
        child anchor=north,
        parent anchor=south,
        l sep+=12.5pt,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[rounded corners=5pt, line width=0.5pt, ->, \forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -|
            (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
    }
    [ Parent,rect={some test text}
        [Variant 1,rect={some test text} ]
        [Variant 2,rect={some test text} ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @bioinfornatics You're welcome!